# iOS15 UITextView After dragging the view, it causes a crash, Invalid parameter not satisfying: pos

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios15, uitextviewdelegate

[crash example](https://qiita.com/Yaruki00/items/219902185610b52a7a0d)

The above article is a problem found by a netizen on the forum. Recently, I also found a similar crash stack on firebase. I guess it is also caused by this reason, and it may be the problem of data out of bounds. Do you have a good solution?

Firebase crashed the stack:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Invalid parameter not satisfying: pos
0
CoreFoundation
__exceptionPreprocess
1
libobjc.A.dylib
objc_exception_throw
2
Foundation
_userInfoForFileAndLine
3
UIKitCore
-[_UITextKitTextPosition compare:]
4
UIKitCore
-[UITextInputController comparePosition:toPosition:]
5
UIKitCore
-[UITextView comparePosition:toPosition:]
6
UIKitCore
-[UITextPasteController _clampRange:]
7
UIKitCore
__87-[UITextPasteController _performPasteOfAttributedString:toRange:forSession:completion:]_block_invoke
8
UIKitCore
__87-[UITextPasteController _performPasteOfAttributedString:toRange:forSession:completion:]_block_invoke.177
9
UIKitCore
-[UITextInputController _pasteAttributedString:toRange:completion:]
10
UIKitCore
-[UITextPasteController _performPasteOfAttributedString:toRange:forSession:completion:]
11
UIKitCore
__49-[UITextPasteController _executePasteForSession:]_block_invoke
12
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
13
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_client_callout
14
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
15
CoreFoundation
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
16
CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopRun
17
CoreFoundation
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
18
GraphicsServices
GSEventRunModal
19
UIKitCore
-[UIApplication _run]
20
UIKitCore
UIApplicationMain
21
HelloTalk_Binary
main.m -  20 
main + 20
```

Comment: Got exact crash also when just pasting text onto UITextView on iOS 15. Answer from @Sibcat also fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

I could not find the reason, but found work around. If I implement one of the two methods of `UITextPasteDelegate` for `UITextView`, `textPasteConfigurationSupporting` or `performPasteOf`, to return string without any attributes, then app does not crash.

```
public func textPasteConfigurationSupporting(
  _ textPasteConfigurationSupporting: UITextPasteConfigurationSupporting,
  performPasteOf attributedString: NSAttributedString,
  to textRange: UITextRange
) -> UITextRange {
  let start = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textRange.start)
  let length = textView.offset(from: textRange.start, to: textRange.end)
  let nsRange = NSRange(location: start, length: length)

  let shouldInsert = textView(
   textView,
   shouldChangeTextIn: nsRange,
   replacementText: attributedString.string
  )

  if shouldInsert {
   textView.replace(textRange, withText: attributedString.string)
  }

  return textRange
}
```

or

```
public func textPasteConfigurationSupporting(
  _ textPasteConfigurationSupporting: UITextPasteConfigurationSupporting,
  combineItemAttributedStrings itemStrings: [NSAttributedString],
  for textRange: UITextRange
) -> NSAttributedString {
  return NSAttributedString(string: itemStrings.map { $0.string }.joined())
}
```

Comment: Thanx! Implementing
func textPasteConfigurationSupporting(
  _ textPasteConfigurationSupporting: UITextPasteConfigurationSupporting,
  performPasteOf attributedString: NSAttributedString,
  to textRange: UITextRange
) -> UITextRange
work for me! (another one don't)
don't forget about
textView.pasteDelegate = self

Comment: There is no crash in iOS iOS 15.5 and iOS 16, is this fixed in a specific iOS 15.x?

Answer (score 1):

@Sibcat has a good catch.

The documentations for the method
`textPasteConfigurationSupporting:performPasteOfAttributedString:toRange:`
says that if you implement this method - no system mechanizm be applied (where the crash occurs)

> It this is not implemented, the standard paste mechanism will be used.
> So just implementing this method the app is protected from the crash.

**Additional note**

The crash occurs only if you return NO as answer from delegate method `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:text`

**Added:**

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    BOOL success = NO;
    
    NSString *newString = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    
    if([self isNumericString:newString] || [newString isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        success = [newString floatValue] <= maxValue
    }
    else
    {
        if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
        {
            [textView resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
    
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the source used for "The crash occurs only if you return NO as answer from delegate method textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:text". please?

Comment: @dubbeat Sorry for the late response.  The added sample just returns NO when the input goes to be not numeric.

Comment: There is no crash in iOS iOS 15.5 and iOS 16, is this fixed in a specific iOS 15.x?